# How to migrate clearcase views from v7.3 to v9.0.x?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

We are migrating from clearcase v7.3 to clearcase v9.0.x? Can someone pls help us how do we migrate the developer views (remote client) as well to avoid developers re-creating the views using Clear Team Explorer?

Thanks,
DZone

Comment: There isn't a clearcase 7.3. You may be referring to the version of the SCM adapter (cc plugin for eclipse). Can you clarify what clearcase version, and what view type you are using?